# Pip "Ignoring invalid distribution" warning

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, python-3.7

For the past few pip package/module installs I have been performing in Windows 10 Command prompt, I am seeing warnings during the installation stating:

```
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -jango (c:\users\myusername\appdata\roaming\python\python37\site-packages)
```

Background system info:
Python version 3.7
Pip version 21.1.1

What is the issue here, and how can I fix this? I looked into some other posts that faced similar issues, but was not able to find any good answers on how to solve it.

Comment: Do you actually have a `-jango` folder inside the `c:\users\myusername\appdata\roaming\python\python37\site-packages` folder?

Comment: Maybe because you have to remove the hyphen or something? Idk.

Answer (score 15):

Not sure how you would have gotten the django folder, only you can answer that!  I'm assuming you mean "django" here not "jango" as "jango" isn't a package.

However if you delete the folder

```
c:\users\myusername\appdata\roaming\python\python37\site-packages\django (or jango, either one)
```

then this error will go away when using pip.  You can then reinstall it again with pip if you decide that you need it.  Obviously make sure nothing is in that folder that you've changed before you do this.

Another thing you could try is renaming the "jango" folder to "django" if it is indeed listed as "jango", perhaps the first letter was removed from the folder name by accident and this is now confusing pip.

Comment: Thanks. In my cast, I have "Ignoring invalid distribution -illow" error after I update pillow. I found that it is because it didn't uninstall old one completely. I manually do it and the warning disappear.

Comment: same error as @蔡易翔. To solve it, I deleted the ~illow folder in `AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Lib\site-packages` as well as the Pillow main folder (same location) and I also did a `PIP uninstall pillow`.

Comment: I went through the same thing with django. It happened when I was updating my django distro, but then stopped it midway with CTRL+C and tried to do it again. I think pip creates a temporary file when it's upgrading packages, and if you stop the upgrade midway, it leaves a partially deleted invalid package or something. Anyway, I solved it by just deleting the extra partial django folder, "~jango" in site-packages.