# Can I remove some python packages start with ~

Tags: python, package

Using python youtube api, I got a error from tensorflow about protobuf version.

But, reinstalling protobuf didn't resolve the problems. also, I can't even remove tensorflow.

then I found that youtube api installs python 3.10.~ version, so I removed it and reinstalled tensorflow-gpu that I used.

Now everything goes well. but, in cmd, there are some warnings that have some weird named packages.

[file explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l6JBI.png)
[cmd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MF7Ct.png)

I think those were created from error when I reinstall packages.

Can I remove thoese package start with ~
ex)~rotobot or ~ensorflow

Comment: As I understand it, those are temporary directories created when a installation fails. They can be removed without causing a problem. See issue tracker here: https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/7269

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do I get this when using pip WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68880743/why-do-i-get-this-when-using-pip-warning-ignoring-invalid-distribution-ip)