# WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution - (c:\python310\lib\site-packages)

Tags: python, pip

Whenever I install a pip library in Python, I get a series of warnings. For example :

> ```
> WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (c:\python310\lib\site-packages)
> WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution - (c:\python310\lib\site-packages)
> WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (c:\python310\lib\site-packages)
> WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution - (c:\python310\lib\site-packages)
> WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (c:\python310\lib\site-packages)
> WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution - (c:\python310\lib\site-packages)
> ```

How can I avoid getting these warnings ?

Comment: Can you check in the `c:\python310\lib\site-packages` folder whether there's some folder that starts with `-ip`? Could be the same problem as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67442661/warning-ignoring-invalid-distribution-ip-c-python39-lib-site-packages-how-d

Comment: This does not work

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67613777/pip-ignoring-invalid-distribution-warning

Answer (score 38, accepted):

the warning below:

[image]

can fix as follows.

go to the lib\site-packages folder, then look for folders starting with ~ like what you see in the picture below

[image]

and mentioned in that warning, then remove them

this can be fixed this warning and no longer appears

Comment: Where exactly can I find the lib/site-packages folder? On my PC, there is no Anaconda3 folder...

Comment: you can find it here in Linux type 'which python'  in windows type

'where python' 

you will get the result as follows

C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe

C:\Users\hp\Anaconda3\python.exe

C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe


in my case
i found it here


C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Lib\site-packages

Comment: On my Windows PC, I found it here: `C:\Users\<USER>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages` and also here: `C:\Python310\Lib\site-packages`. Strange, but it seems that Python311 likes to install into AppData, while Python310 is in the root `C:`.